# how can nested grids for hierarchical data be created using Windows Forms Controls?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, datagridview

I'm looking for a way to create a DataGridView that has rows that when clicked expand to reveal another datagridview right below them. Is this possible to accomplish without creating a brand new datagridview-like control or am I better off displaying the nested datagridviews elsewhere?

(Here's an article that explains how to do it in ASP.NET. however, it's not clear whether it can be done with Windows Forms:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164077.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will allways need a custom control (free or paid) to achive this.

[Tree View with Columns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns)[(free under CPOL)](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx)

[DevExpress XtraGrid (paid)](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/)

[Janus GridEx (paid)](http://www.janusys.com/controls/)